# Is there any way to access the current label set in JavaScript/ActionScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, namespaces, clone, labeled-statements

If I create a trivial [labeled statement](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/jslint.html#labels) such as:

```
foo: do { alert('hi') } while (false)
```

Is there any way to clone foo?

Comment: I don't think so, but are you using labels for performance reasons? Why not use a function?

Comment: I am just going through the spec and using parts of the language I haven't used before.

Comment: you want to use the **javascript** tag for these questions.  _jscript_ questions are specific to the Microsoft implementation of ECMAScript.

Comment: @DanD. what? No, they are for `continue` and `break`, JS never had `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apparently this is not possible. Labels cannot be used in an assignment statement and the scope of a label is the conditional block of the loop in which it is defined.

```
pastureLoop:
for (i = 0; i < pastureLen; i++)
{
   var pasture = pastures[i];
   var cows = pasture.getCows();

   var j, numCows = cows.length;
   for (j = 0; j < numCows; j++)
   {
      var cow = cows[j];
      if (cow.isSick())
         { break pastureLoop; }

      healthyCows++;
   }
}


pastureLoop:
for (i = 0; i < pastureLen; i++)
{
   var pasture = pastures[i];
   var cows = pasture.getCows();

   var j, numCows = cows.length;
   for (j = 0; j < numCows; j++)
   {
      var cow = cows[j];
      if (cow.isEating())
         { continue pastureLoop; }
   }

   // No cows were eating, so fire the callback for pasture[i]
   pasture.executeCallback();    // or whatever
}
```

The closest alternative is a labelled function declaration in non-strict mode:

> B.3.2 Labelled Function Declarations
>
> Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the specification of `LabelledStatement` did not allow for the association of a statement label with a `FunctionDeclaration`. However, a labelled `FunctionDeclaration` was an allowable extension for non-strict code and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations supported that extension. In ECMAScript 2015, the grammar productions for `LabelledStatement` permits use of `FunctionDeclaration` as a `LabelledItem` but 13.13.1 includes an Early Error rule that produces a Syntax Error if that occurs. For web browser compatibility, that rule is modified with the addition of the underlined text:
>
> LabelledItem : FunctionDeclaration

```
It is a Syntax Error if any strict mode source code matches this rule.
```

This can be used to create a declaration which is inaccessible:

```
function show_alert()
  {
  label:
    {
    break label;
    var foo = 1;
    }
  console.log(foo);
  }
```

but can be made accessible through string manipulation and the function constructor.

**References**

- [ECMAScript-6 Annex B, Section 3.2: Labelled Function Declarations](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-labelled-function-declarations)
- [Loop unrolling and completion-values in es6](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/loop-unrolling-and-completion-values-in-es6)
- [The JavaScript Goto](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/09/the-javascript-goto-statement/)
- [Speed up your JavaScript, Part 1](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/)